# Calculate percentage with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structures

Languages:

```
id  |  language
1   |  English
2   |  Dutch
```

Translations:

```
id | translation_id | translation | language_id
1  |                | Username    | 1
2  |                | Password    | 1
3  | 2              | Wachtwoord  | 2
```

I tried the following query to get an overview for each language:

```
SELECT
  `languages`.`id`,
  `language`
  concat( round( ( COUNT(`translations`.`languages_id` = 1) / COUNT(`translations`.`languages_id` = 2)) * 100, 0), '%') AS `percentage`
FROM `languages`
JOIN `translations`
ON  `languages`.`id` = `translations`.`languages_id`
```

But for some reason I'm only getting 100% for percentage. While I would expect to get 50% for Dutch.

The result I get right now is just

```
[id] => 1 [language] => English [percentage] => 100%
```

While I would expect to get:

```
[id] => 1 [language] => English [percentage] => 100%
[id] => 2 [language] => Dutch [percentage] => 50%
```

I know I have no translations linked for English.

In this case English is the default language so that would be 100% every other language is a certain percentage of English. That's why I expect Dutch to be 50%.

Also wouldn't it be possible to get the percentage for every language without doing the same query for every language? Just like when only selecting the id and language you would get both `2, Dutch` and `1, English` rows returned.

Comment: Kindly provide the result you are getting and the expected result.

Comment: @Viki888 Changed the question

Comment: Can you elaborate the calculation for percentage?

Comment: Is Dutch 50% because there is no translation for Username? If so, is English supposed to be the complete set ?

Comment: @GurV exactly. Just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find count of rows for each language and divide it with count of english language like this:

Try this:

```
select l.*, concat(round(100 * count(t.languages_id) / t2.cnt,0),'%')
from languages l
left join translations t
on l.id = t.languages_id
cross join (
    select count(*) cnt
    from translations
    where languages_id = 1
) t2
group by l.id;
```

Comment: I just noticed that when there is nothing translated it still returns a few percent like: `2%` when it should be `0%` Do you know what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: @SuperDJ It's due to `count(*)`. I've updated my answer to use `count(t.languages_id)` instead. Can you try this?

Comment: Thanks that fixed it